# Completion time of "_invalidate_internal" in Matplotlib increases linearly over extended periods. What is this function doing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, internals, invalidation

I am running a Python Tkinter GUI application for multiple days (ideally it will run continuously without needing to be restarted). After a few days, the program typically crashes with no explanation or error messages. I have used cProfile to profile the animation functionality of our Matplotlib graphs and search for possible slow-down points. The results clearly showed that the only function which increased in execution time over the program run period was this one:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py:134(_invalidate_internal)

I've looked at the Matplotlib source code (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/transforms.py), but I haven't been able to figure out what this function is doing. **What does _invalidate_internal do, and is there anything I can do to prevent it from taking so long to execute?**

For more context, our program has several animated matplotlib plots which graph inputs from sensor data over time. We plot the n most recent data points on each frame so that it gives the effect of a scrolling graph. Here is the animation code:

```
def animate(ii):

while True:
    most_recent_time_graphed = param_dict[param_list[0]] #first, pulls up first plot
    most_recent = reader.query_by_num(table="SensorData", num=1)
    reader.commit()         #if identical, do not animate
    #then checks that plot's time list
    if  (len(most_recent) == 0):
        break
    
    #time_reader = datetime.strptime(most_recent[0][0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    time_reader = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent[0][0])
    if (len(most_recent_time_graphed.tList) != 0) and (time_reader == most_recent_time_graphed.tList[0]):
        for i, param in enumerate(param_list, 1):
            current_text = live_dict[param]
            current_text.label.config(text=most_recent[0][i], fg="black", bg="white")
        break #checks if the timestamp is exactly the same as prior, i.e. no new data points have been logged in this frame
    #do I have to add an else?

    else:
        config_settings = csv_read()
        c0, c1, c2 = config_dict['enable_text'], config_dict['num_config'], config_dict['provider_config']
        c3, c4, c5 = config_dict['email_config'], config_dict['upper_config'], config_dict['lower_config']
        for i, key in enumerate(param_dict, 1):
            current_plot = param_dict[key]
            current_param_val = float(most_recent[0][i])
            current_text = live_dict[key] #update to live text data summary
            if current_param_val > float(config_settings[c4][i-1]) or current_param_val < float(config_settings[c5][i-1]):
                #only send text if enable_text is True
                if config_settings[c0] == [str(True)]:
                ###sends text if new problem arises or every 5  minutes
                    if allIsGood[key] and Minute[key] == None:
                        print('new problem')
                        Minute[key] = datetime.now().minute
                        minuta[key] = Minute[key]
                        pCheck(float(config_settings[c4][i-1]),float(config_settings[c5][i-1]),key,current_param_val,config_settings[c1],config_settings[c2]) #uncomment to test emergency texts
                    elif allIsGood[key] == False and abs(Minute[key] - datetime.now().minute) % 5 == 0 and not (minuta[key] == datetime.now().minute):
                        print('same problem')
                        minuta[key] = datetime.now().minute
                        pCheck(float(config_settings[c4][i-1]),float(config_settings[c5][i-1]),key,current_param_val,config_settings[c1],config_settings[c2]) #uncomment to test emergency texts
                        #pass
                    
                    #setting the parameter to not ok
                    allIsGood[key] = False

                current_text.label.config(text=most_recent[0][i], fg="red", bg="white")
                current_plot.plot_color = 'r'
            
            else:
                current_text.label.config(text=most_recent[0][i], fg="black", bg="white")
                current_plot.plot_color = 'g'
                
                ###setting the parameter back to true and sending "ok" text 
                if allIsGood[key] == False:
                    Minute[key] = None
                    allOk(key,config_settings[c1],config_settings[c2])
                    pass
                
                allIsGood[key] = True

            data_stream = current_plot.incoming_data
            time_stream = current_plot.tList
            data_stream.insert(0, most_recent[0][i])
            #time_f = datetime.strptime(most_recent[0][0], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            time_f = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(most_recent[0][0])
            time_stream.insert(0, time_f)
            if len(data_stream) < 20: #graph updates, growing to show 20 points
                current_plot.make_plot()
            else:                      #there are 20 points and more available, so animation occurs
                data_stream.pop()
                time_stream.pop()
                current_plot.make_plot()
        break
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited to include animate code and add specific question about _invalidate_internal.